# Magento - JS/JQuery Issue? Add to Cart and Login Non-functioning

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, magento, e-commerce

So I have searched around stackoverflow.  We recently took over a client and the site is www.buypipeflanges.com - Site is having the following issues after correcting and updating Magento files for some other issues:

-Add to Cart doesn't add anything, page refreshes, but nothing is in the cart.

-If I enable 1 page checkout and "redirect to cart after adding product" it   just goes to "shopping cart empty" page.

-Customer cannot log in.  Customer just gets circled back around.

I can find no jQuery conflicts or issues, there is no error showing in "var" cookie lifetime is 86400, I removed the compression of all JS to one file.  Nothing fixes the issue.  Even went as far as reinstalling the majority of the core Magento files.  And removing a bunch of plugins to assure it wasn't plugin related.

Any ideas?

Thanks ahead of time!

Also Magento Version is 1.9.1.1 CE

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you check your var/session folder for necessary write permissions on your web server user. If Magento is unable to create a new session file (assuming you're using files for session storage and not DB), then it would manifest as the issues you described.